# Switching off the bootstrap host causing the whole cluster down in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

MarkLogic version used `9.0-10.4`

There are 6 hosts in the cluster. On shutting off the bootstrap host the whole cluster went down.
None of the hosts `8001` port is opening.

Not able to figure it out the reason behind this. Please help.

Comment: Sounds like something that would happen when Security db is not replicated, making bootstrap host single-point of failure. Let me see if we can dig up docs on this..

Comment: Ohh yes you are right. will create security replicas and see how it works!

Comment: Observed, need to create replicas for schemas db as well(along with security) although we are not dependent on schemas db (we use our own schemas db 'project-schemas')

Comment: Yes, and it is recommended to replicate a few more. We found some relevant pieces of doc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is necessary to have failover configured for some of the internal databases, as they are used in various places. Security database is very obvious, but also Schemas needs to be replicated, as many databases have it as default schemas db.

The general recommendation is described in the section **Configuring the Security and Auxiliary Databases to Use Failover Forests** of our clustering guide:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cluster/config-both-failover#id_57935

For further reading I'm also providing this KnowledgeBase article about replacing failed node in a cluster, in case you find it useful:

https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/607/15/replacing-a-failed-marklogic-node-in-a-cluster-a-step-by-step-walkthrough

HTH!